# Total memory requested by Pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have a pod with 3 containers packaged.

1. Main app container
2. Two Sidecars to support app container.

Main app container has below Request configurations

1. CPU = 2 Cores
2. Memory = 4 GB

Sidecar1 container has below Request configurations

1. CPU = 1 Core
2. Memory = 2 GB

Sidecar1 container has below Request configurations

1. CPU = 2
2. Memory = 3 GB

I need to find the total CPU cores and Memory requested by a Pod. I am adding CPU/Memory requested by main app container and all sidecars as below
Total CPU Requested = 2 + 1 + 2 = 5 Cores
Total Memory Requested = 4 + 2 + 3 = 9 GB

Is it correct to say that Pod has requested 5 Cores and 8 GB of memory?

I described pod to find the Requested CPU and Memory using below command
kubectl describe pod <POD_NAME>